# Unification of Electromagnetism and Gravitation

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity, theory-of-everything

Is it true that this can be accomplished in 5 dimensions? (Kaluza-Klein  model)
It seems that Einstein liked this idea but it didn't completely unify all forces.
Recent commentators say that this fifth dimension is compactified perhaps even to the Planck length scale. the reason for this is that The fifth dimension is not obvious in our everyday experience.
Perhaps  a fifth force is identified with this 5th dimension being dark matter.
Two Brazilian physicists connected the notion of force in special relativity (admittedly an approximation since Force usually involves acceleration) with a torsion based geometry.
They considered spin to be a manifestation of torsion.

Comment: Have you tried a web search?

Comment: I prefer print media to web searches.

Comment: @Larry yet you asked it online?

Comment: Yes but I prefer print media like books overall.

Comment: Which books did you read?

Comment: IF time is quantized as a chronon (not original to me) and space is quantized in terms of the Planck constant, quantizing general relativity might be around the corner. One book I read was general relativitand y I matter by Mendel Sachs. He does not talk about cronin's and Planck lengths but mostly about spinors.

Comment: The speed of light c is a constant. This could be Planck's constant / chronon.

Comment: Space and time are not absolute. The invariant interval of special relativity is.

Comment: I one interpretation of the chronon is it is related to the charge and mass of the electron. There ratio is equivalent to the magnetic mechanical ratio. This is an invariance like the invariant interval.

Comment: Lorentz transformation relates cronons of one frame with those of another. And likewise the Planck lengths.

Comment: Time dilation isf the expansion of the cronon and the contraction of the Planck length.

Comment: These variable quantities cannot be less than there quantum constants.

Comment: The electron interacts with virtual photons in the quantum vacuum. It also interacts with virtual gravitons.

Comment: Hence, in a very restricted sense the electron represents a unified field theory of electromagnetism and gravitation.

Comment: the gravitons of an asymmetrical capacitor interact with the gravitons of the earth since both have positive polarity they repel each other.

Comment: Since gravity is normally attractive the asymmetry makes the gravity repulsive.

Comment: In hs book on special and general relativity Einstein believe an asymmetric theory would unite electromagnetism and gravitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toes today have more than 5 dimensions. There are more than two forces, electromagnetism and gravitation. In one unification there is electromagnetism andn the weak Force. Thereit is in fact the unification of all the fundamental forces except for gravitation. However if I'm rnot mistaken true toes are 11 or 21 dimensions.

Comment: An important thing to realize is that each force yois quantized with particles such as photons gravitons and so forth.